# why isn't bashrc file visible using find | grep "file" in wsl?

Tags: command-line, windows, filesystem, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bashrc

Thanks for coming to my post :)

I was wondering, just out of curiosity, why isn't the .bashrc file visible in wsl using the

`find | grep file` command

and visible using

`ls -al ~/ | more`

command ?

I'm using administrator privileges, why is it not visible?
My setup is a linux distro running on wsl.

Comment: `find | grep file` will only output files whose names contain the string `file`

Comment: That does it for me. Thanks bro 

Answer (score 1):

The following answer applies only to Windows 10 Pro OS build 19041.685 and Ubuntu installed ONLY as WSL1.  I don't know how bash will behave when Ubuntu is installed as WSL2.

When you start a bash session via the **Windows Terminal > Ubuntu**, according to the default shell prompt (PS1), the directory that you see first is `user_name@computer_name:/mnt/c/Users/user_name`.  That is your user's default folder for Windows -- `C:\Users\user_name`, but it is not your user's home directory for bash!

At the bash shell prompt, type `cd`.  That takes you to your bash home directory, and `ls -a` will display all the dot bash files in it:  `.bash_history`, `.bash_logout`, `.bashrc`, and `.profile`.

Append anything that you want to `.profile` to set up your preferred environment.